# Intermediate fields $K((K^{1/p^\infty} \cap L)^{p^\infty})$ and $K(K(L^{p^\infty}))^{1/p^\infty} \cap L $ of field extension $L/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p >0$ and $L/K$ an algebraic
extension. We can assoicate to these fields two canonical operations:

The *perfect closure*  a $K^{1/p^{\infty}} := \bigcup_{i \le 1} K^{1/p^i}$
and the other thing (I don't know it's name) $K(L^{p^\infty}) := \bigcap_{i \ge 1} K(L^{p^i})$.

Question: how are these operators related to each other in the sense
of what we do know generally about intermediate fields
$K((K^{1/p^\infty} \cap L)^{p^\infty})$ and
$K(K(L^{p^\infty}))^{1/p^\infty} \cap L $ of $L/K$ which are
as compositions of these two operations 'within the $L/K$ universe'?

Comment: More fun when adding $L^H$ (the subfield fixed by the $K$ embeddings) and the extension of $K$ generated by the coefficients of $\prod_{h\in H} (X-h(a))$ for each $a\in L$ (thisone has no name too, though it is $=L^H$ when $L/K$ is normal) and composition with above operations

Comment: are there some structural results known 
or does it highly depend of choosen $K$ and $L$?

Comment: If $[L:K]$ is finite then

$K\subset K((K^{1/p^\infty} \cap L)^{p^\infty})\subset K((K^{1/p^{[L:K]}})^{p^\infty})=K$, when $L/K$ is infinite then $K((K^{1/p^\infty} \cap L)^{p^\infty})$ is adding to $K$ the $p^\infty$-th roots of elements having their $p^\infty$-th roots in $L$.

Comment: $K(L^{p^\infty}) = L\cap K^{sep}$ and $L/(L\cap K^{sep})$ is purely inseparable so $(K(L^{p^\infty}))^{1/p^\infty}$ contains $L$, it is $=L^{1/p^\infty}$.

Comment: do you know where I can look up the proofs of theese inclusions?

Comment: I'm interested in this one: $K((K^{1/p^\infty} \cap L)^{p^\infty})\subset K((K^{1/p^{[L:K]}})^{p^\infty})=K$